# Trying to visualize the sum of daily fees based on user status, using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

Sample Data:

```
Date        user_type        fees
21/05/2012  Customer         100
21/05/2012  Customer         200
21/05/2012  Subscriber       100
22/05/2012  Customer         50
```

I want to display a line chart for every day, the line chart should have two lines one for each user type (Customer or Subscriber). The values for the lines in the chart are the sum of daily fees, for example at 21/05/2012 the Customer line should be valued at 300, while the subscriber line at 100.

X-axis is date, Y-axis is sum of daily fees.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following code:

```
df2 = df.groupby(["Date", "user_type"]).sum().reset_index()
```

Here, first you group all your DataFrame based on the date and the user_type, and then sum all columns (in this case, just `fees`) to see the aggregate of each (date, user_type) pair. Then you can reset_index because otherwise you will have one date mapping to many values, and that's not good for making plots.

Then you can plot what you want just filtering the user_type, plotting each line based on one filter.

Comment: Thank you! I'm fairly new to this so may I ask how would I create the filter?

Comment: I used df2[df2["user_type"]=="Customer"], plot it and you will get the line for customer. Then df2[df2["user_type"]=="Subscriber"]. The first "df2" stands for the column you're plotting. Then df2["user_type"]=="Customer"] is the real filter. What you're doing is like selecting a column, but instead you select a filtered DF.